# Thinger.IO endpoints return "rate limit reached" without any further explanation

Tags: arduino, iot, esp8266

I have a couple of IoT devices hosted on [Thinger.IO](https://thinger.io/) and as part of their code execution from time to time they try to invoke [thinger.io endpoints](https://docs.thinger.io/features/endpoints-1). This basically is their way of letting you connect with your business back-end services and handle IoT devices events.

It basically looks something like this:
[image]

as here at step **3** we make a reference to [Thinger.IO's input resources](https://docs.thinger.io/quick-sart/coding-guide#input-resources). This basically lets your back-end to invoke functions on your IoT device. **The issue that I am facing right now is related to step 2**

My endpoints just stopped getting invoked. When I try to test the endpoint using their embedded client:
[image]

I get an error which is saying:
[image]

I don't really understand that. The last time an endpoint was invoked was on the 27th of February (5 days ago) and since then I've had my device completely turned off.

**SIDE NOTE:** The problem is not with my back-end because we can successfully invoke the endpoint using Postman.

Comment: If it works with Postman then it probably _is_ your device.

Comment: @romkey Well, for that purpose, as I mentioned, I am going on thinger.io's platform and I am trying to invoke the endpoint from there. The error occurs there which makes me think there's something wrong with the endpoint (which has nothing in common with my device).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thee free cloud (community version) of Thinger.io has some rate limiters to throttle requests per user. However, it seems that you are not reaching those limits, so it should be a bug introduced in latest release 2.9.9 in Community Version. Will look into it. Thanks for reporting.

Edit: It should be fixed now in 2.9.91 version. Consider using a private cloud instance if you are connecting a couple of devices ;)

Comment: Thanks for the fix. Just one side question, what if I am planning to host a lot more devices on Thinger? Would it be better to stay on Thinger's cloud or I would need my private one?

Comment: Glad to know it works! If you are planning to connect a lot more devices, i would deploy a private instance that suits your needs: https://pricing.thinger.io Public community version does not offer all the options and are rate-limited.  At this moment we are not offering deploying more devices in the community version.